# Azure devops agent fails when extracting task: The directory is not empty

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a random and intermittent problem with a self-hosted agent failing to extract tasks. In this case CopyFiles task.

```
##[debug]Extracting task cbdaa6bc4190917ecfa689a5bda8 from C:\azagent\A1\_work\_taskzips\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c_2.190.1.zip to C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.190.1.
##[error]The directory is not empty. : 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.190.1'
##[debug]System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty. : 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.190.1'
```

Anyone who has encountered this?

Comment: No, but we sometimes get this:
Prepare build directory.
##[error]The directory is not empty. : 'D:\_work\2'

And this is because someone has logged into the build machine and had a Explorer.exe open inside that folder path. Closing the explorer window and kicking off a build again fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by Real-time protection locking files